Как сделать кнопку в disnake
row = disnake.ui.ActionRow
row.add_button(label='1', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.success, emoji='✅')
await channel('rul').send(content=content, embeds=embeds, view=row)

выдаёт что-то следущее:
TypeError: ActionRow.add_button() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

что я делаю не так?(да, я тупой есть куча гайдов на эту тему, но я всё равно ничего не понел)

Вы почти правильно всё написали, но есть небольшая ошибка в синтаксисе. При создании объекта ActionRow, вы забыли вызвать его как класс (не забывайте ставить круглые скобки). Также, при отправке компонента, нужно использовать параметр components, а не view. Вот как должно быть правильно:
# Создаем ActionRow
row = disnake.ui.ActionRow()
# Добавляем кнопку в ActionRow
row.add_button(label='1', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.success, emoji='✅')

# Отправляем сообщение с ActionRow
await channel('rul').send(content=content, embeds=embeds, components=[row])

